# Convert Absolute Positioning Into Relative Positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, css-position

Sorry if this is already out there somewhere, but I've been looking for a while and haven't found anything.  I'd like to know if there's any way to, given the x and y coordinates/offset for an absolutely positioned element on a page, change that element into a relatively positioned element, but have it stay in the same visual spot, changing its location in the DOM.  For example, given this html

```
<div id="divOne"></div>
<div id="divTwo"></div>
<div id="divThree"></div>
```

if divOne were positioned absolutely and its position happened to visually fall between divTwo and divThree, is there a way for me to convert its x,y position so I would be able to tell jQuery to place it after divOne and before divTwo in the DOM?  I'm well versed in Javascript and jQuery, I'm just looking for a method I may not know about or for an answer from someone who may have come across this before.

Comment: Stupid question warning: Why don't just keep it absolute?

Comment: Because I'm changing it to absolute positioning for the sake of dragging it around the screen.  I'd like to be able to release the mouse button and wherever I release it, it reinserts itself into the DOM at the appropriate position.  I've already written the dragging script.  I just need the dropping back into the DOM part.

Comment: @SamuelReid how will letting them stay absolutely positioned after dragging them hurt any thing?

Comment: It will technically prevent me from allowing the html to be responsive... but it's possible.  But since this is going to be used as part of a tool that others will be using, it will be more convenient for them to be able to drop the element back into the DOM.  Otherwise I'd need to develop some kind of grid snapping thing so people aren't just placing elements that don't line up with each other.

Comment: @SamuelReid oh.  Well if thats the case you can look into something like the jquery ui.  It has a pretty nice drag and drop type system.  Other than that, I guess you could define a set of base coordinates and officially resort the dragged div based on the coordinates upon click release.

Comment: I'm a big fan of jQueryUI, but I'm also not prepared to include an entire suite of features into an app if I only plan on using one thing.  I'll probably end up changing it to leave everything positioned absolutely and just snap them to a grid to allow for better designing.

Answer (score 0):

by removing the absolute positioning of the dragged div you must place its tag to a different place in the dom in order to get it repositioned.

For example if you drag #divOne so that it visually moves between #divTwo and #divThree what you should do is remove the absolute positioning of #divOne and move its tag between the two other divs:

```
<div id="divTwo"></div>
<div id="divOne"></div>
<div id="divThree"></div>
```

If you have a well-defined grid this will work.

If I were you what I would do is to give a standard class to any div in my grid that I want be re-arrangeable. E.g., the class "arrangeable". When the drag-end fires I would calculate where my dragged div must be placed in the dom using this formula:

The dragged div should be moved to another place on the dom. What it will happen is that the dragged div will take the place of an existing one and "push" the existing just after it. For example by dragging #divOne between #divTwo and #divThree, #divOne takes the place of #divThree and pushes it after it. Supposing that the user stops the drag and releases left click when the dragged div is over the existing div whose place is going to be taken (let's name it "pushedDiv") by the dragged one then all you have to do is to recognize the pushedDiv, remove the dragged one from the dom, place right before the recognized one and make its position relative.

In order to realize which is the pushedDiv you can use this routine:

```
//on drag end, where mouse has x and y coords:
var pushedDiv;
$(".arrangeable").each(function(index,value){
    var theoffset = $(this).offset();
    if(x >= theoffset .left && x <= theoffset .left + $(this).width() && y >= theoffset .top && y <= theoffset .top + $(this).height()){
         pushedDiv = $(this);
    }
});
// if pushedDiv is still null then the user didn't release the left click over a div of class "arrangeable". Else, the pushedDiv will be the one we are looking for
```

Comment: `you must place its tag to a different place in the dom in ordeer to get it repositioned` That's exactly what I want to do.  And I like your solution.  A lot, actually.  Unfortunately I don't think it's sufficient considering the placement will not work if the mouse is released over the parent element between the divTwo and divThree, in which case it should still place the element.  For this I think I'll have to do something along the lines of calculating the closest element to the mouse when it is released, and then, as you said, replace it and put the replaced element after the dropped one.